# Loading different Symfony validations dynamically without groups

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I want to add more Validation dynamically inside a Action controller. I have a generic validations in `config/validator/validation.yaml` but I want to load and add other validations depends on a logic inside the action controller in Symfony 4. I **don't** want to do this with **validation groups** because I'm going to have a lot of possibilities and I prefer a different file for each logic.

```php
public function myAction(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator) 
{
...
    if($something){
        //load a validation1.yaml
    }
    else{
        //load a validation2.yaml
    }
    $violations = $validator->validate($user);
...
}
```

Generic validation.yaml:

```
App\Entity\User:
  properties:
    email:
     - NotBlank:
         message: "'email' is a mandatory field."
```

In my validation1.yaml:

```
App\Entity\User:
  properties:
    firstName:
      - NotBlank:
          message: "'FirstName' is a mandatory field."
```

And other constraints in my validation2.yaml:

```
App\Entity\User:
  properties:
```

Comment: Hello, what about validation groups? https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

Comment: @Nek I don't want to do this whit groups because I should have a lot of groups. And If I want to add more group in the future, I should have to add this group to each constraints. I prefer to have partner1.yaml, partner2.yaml ... than groups [partner1, partner2...] in each property

Comment: Then you have to configure the validator by yourself. You can create a validator factory (Symfony Service) that creates the validator for you. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator/resources.html#the-file-loaders